# How do you move 128-bit values between XMM registers?

Tags: assembly, simd, sse

Seemingly trivial problem in assembly: I want to copy the whole XMM0 register to XMM3. I've tried

```
movdq xmm3, xmm0
```

but MOVDQ cannot be used to move values between two XMM registers. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's `movapd`, `movaps`, or `movdqa`

```
movaps xmm3, xmm0
```

They all do the same thing, but there's a catch:

- `movapd` and `movaps` operate in the floating-point domain.
- `movdqa` operates in the integer domain

Use the appropriate one according to your datatype to avoid domain-changing stalls.

Also, there's no reason to use `movapd`. Always use `movaps` instead because `movapd` takes an extra byte to encode.

Comment: movdqa is what I was looking for :) Thanks. That was quick :) PS. How do floating point moves actually differ from the integer ones? To me both should be simple copying...

Comment: On Intel processors, there are separate FP and integer units. When you execute an instruction that is in one unit, the value is moved to that unit. But when you issue an instruction in a different domain to that value, it must be moved to the new unit - with a 1-2 cycle penalty. Therefore, it's best to keep a value in a domain if possible - hence why there are different `mov` instructions. If you're doing integer arithmetic and you use `movaps`, you'll pay a penalty to move the value to the FP unit, and another penalty to move it back on the next integer instruction issued to it.

Comment: Same applies to the logical operators: such as: `por`, `orps`, and `orpd`

Comment: @lampak: SIMD-Integer and FP share a register file, but there are separate bypass forwarding networks to reduce the combinatorial explosion of possible forwarding needed from outputs to inputs of different execution units.  Getting from one domain to the other takes extra latency but not extra uops.  https://agner.org/optimize/ has some details about it in his microarchitecture guide, and see Intel's optimization guide: for Skylake the bypass latency can actually depend on which execution port `orps` happens to pick, rather than the instruction mnemonic.

Comment: Also Haswell/Skylake can have a weird effect where domain-crossing latency affects the *other* operand of instructions using the register result indefinitely (presumably until xsave/xrstor on a context switch).  So be careful about using integer bithacks to generate FP constants! [Haswell AVX/FMA latencies tested 1 cycle slower than Intel's guide says](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64116679)