# How to exchange values between XMM registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse

Is there an x86 instruction or two for exchanging values between XMM registers; similar to XCHG instruction? Can not use memory, a scratch register, or XOR copy.

Comment: The arithmetic version of the XOR swap then? But why can't you use anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you move 128-bit values between XMM registers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671438/how-do-you-move-128-bit-values-between-xmm-registers)

Comment: @BrettHale he's have to use a scratch register for that

Comment: If you think about it, for xchg to work it must use a sneaky register or memory location somewhere in the first place to swap the values over. If you can "use nothing" then only xor will do it. It looks like they never made this facility available for the xmm register set

Comment: I've got 2 versions of a high speed asm routine and the only difference between them is the xor xor xor bits have xchg replacing them. The xor version is as steady as a rock but Gawd only knows what's going on with the xchg version, the output page completely disappears until the routine has ended. It works, but something is happening which messes things about.

Comment: @ady: `xchg` has an implicit lock prefix, which can impose *serious* penalties.

Comment: IMO xchg is really a "macro" hard coded into the original x86 instruction set. It looks like a single instruction... but it aint

Comment: So if as Brett sez, xchg inposes serious penalties for execution speed, then it stands to reason that the designers would deliberately exclude this speedbump instruction from the xmm superspeedy opcode set

Comment: @ady that makes no sense at all, the problem with `xchg` is that it has an implicit lock if it has a memory operand. It's not an inherent problem with exchanging. An exchange between two xmm registers would have been just fine. They could even implement it with register renaming, making it 0-latency (they do it for `fxch` so why not). I suspect the reason it doesn't exist is that it's not necessary often enough - you can just use a scratch register..

Comment: Well I aint no expert but my asm proggy has a 100% registers situation with xchg/xor transpostitions as the sole difference and there's something going on. No memory op is asked for nor required

Comment: I am an 'expert' and I can promise you that `xchg` is handled correctly by and and every x86-based cpu on the consumer market.  Furthermore there's nothing 'sneaky' about it; it isn't even unique in being an instruction that writes back to 2 regs (div, cwd, etc do as well).  As Harold said, modern CPUs could just as well handle it at the renaming stage, though I think they haven't bothered due to how infrequently the instruction is used in production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the completely untested code for the [arithmetic swap](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingValuesSubAdd):

```
vpsubd xmm0, xmm1
vpaddd xmm1, xmm0
vpsubd xmm0, xmm1, xmm0
```

Unlike xor, subtraction is not commutative, so you you end up with that unfortunate last line which you can't really do without avx (well, you can, but with a scratch register and then you're better off using moves).

Using a scratch register would be faster on most processors (except P4 I suppose, but no one cares about P4, right?). On older processors because the first two moves could execute in parallel, on newest processors because they handle xmm reg-reg moves in the front-end, using register renaming. Neither register renaming nor handling instructions purely with renaming are new tricks, renaming has been used since the Pentium Pro and `fxch` is typically implemented using renaming. Implementing xmm reg-reg moves with register renaming is a fairly new trick though, it's in Ivy Bridge, Haswell, Bulldozer and Piledriver.

Often you can get rid of an exchange in a loop by unrolling it by 2. Exchanges not in loops are rarely necessary and even more rarely a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

The real value in the `xchg` operation is its use in sync primitives, spinlocks, etc. It can impose heavy penalties, due to its implicit `lock` prefix. Certainly no one would implement sync primitives using SSE, but would an exchange have any merit? It might be useful on occasion, but with 8 SSE registers in 32-bit mode, and 16 in 64-bit mode, why *not* simply use an SSE scratch register? I don't know if any x86-64 processors use register renaming, etc.,in their SIMD units (to eliminate false dependencies).

You've ruled out using `xorps` (or the `_mm_xor_ps` intrinsic), which is typically a useless trick on modern processors anyway - certainly with general purpose registers, and you've ruled out the use of memory. That's all your possibilities exhausted, I'm afraid. To summarise: No.

Comment: The implicit lock only occurs only if one of the operands is a memory location.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `PXOR` instruction is the shortest and fastest way to exchange the content between XMM registers. This code exchange the content between xmm0 and xmm1.

```
  pxor  xmm0, xmm1
  pxor  xmm1, xmm0
  pxor  xmm0, xmm1
```

So, where you can see a problem?