# Are there several same-effect instructions in SSE/AVX?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, avx

I'm learning X86 assembly, when I learn SSE and AVX instructions, I found that there are several instructions which don't share the same opcode but have the same effect. For example:

all of `MOVAPS`, `MOVAPD` and `MOVDQA` move 128/256 bits aligned data from/to xmm/ymm.

all of `PAND`, `ANDPS` and `ANDPD` and the same with other bitwise operations do bitwise operations on each bit.

I have checked intel manual but I can't tell the difference. What are the differences among them if they are different? or Why don't they share the same opcode if they are the same?

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8671461/547981) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998071/547981) TL;DR: due to how the cpu is implemented you can later get a penalty if you use the wrong domain (float or integer).